# Syntax help required

Tags: c#, .net

Can someone help with the following:

```
CollectionView.Filter = m => ((Customer)m).Name.ToLower().Contains(_lastNameFilter);
```

Instead of looking up name, I'd to search `DateAdded = _filterDate`

Comment: Considering that you are getting *free quality help*, saying "urgent" does sound kind of selfish.

Comment: I don't mean to abuse the service but I really need to get this out in an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it should be:

```
CollectionView.Filter = m => 
    ((Customer)m).DateAdded == DateTime.Parse(_filterDate);
```

Comment: Should I delare _filterDate as date? Currently it's a string

Comment: @Jim - If DateAdded is a string, then yes. You should be comparing values of the same type.

Comment: I got "Operator == cannot be applied to operands of type Systsm.Date.Time? and string

Comment: @Jim - I've updated the code. This should work depending on the format at of the string.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks, but how can check the content of _filerDate because executing the statement.  If it is not a date  there, it crashes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how `CollectionView.Filter` works, but why don't you just use this:

```
CollectionView.Filter = m => ((Customer)m).DateAdded == _filterDate;
```

Comment: I got "Operator == cannot be applied to operands of type Systsm.Date.Time? and string

Comment: Please do some thinking yourself... You can't be a programmer without thinking ;-) I can't say much to your problem, because I don't know, why `_filterDate` is a string, when it should be a `DateTime`!

Comment: I know it should be a datetime.  I'm new to this platform.  It is a textbox which I can't decalre it as a date, can I?  THe problem is I don't know how to convert it to a date before executing filtering.

Answer (score 1):

With the assumption that `_filterDate` is a string and `DateAdded` a Date
    CollectionView.Filter = m => ((Customer)m).DateAdded == DateTime.Parse(_filterDate);

Comment: I got "Operator == cannot be applied to operands of type Systsm.Date.Time? and string